# .htaccess redirection except specific paths

Tags: redirect, https

I am using opencart on a Godaddy hosting with cpanel. I am using a .htaccess file to do the following with no success.
I am trying to redirect everything from "http://northfalcons.com" or "http://www.northfalcons.com" to “https://northfalcons.com”.

But following three pages:

```
1.https://northfalcons.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=60
2.https://northfalcons.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=61
3.https://northfalcons.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=62
```

Need to be redirected to http instead of https, like follows:

```
1.http://northfalcons.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=60
2.http://northfalcons.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=61
3.http://northfalcons.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=62
```

How do I do this? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First You can Backup Your `.htaccess` files:

After Replace Following `.htaccess` code in Your Root `.htaccess` file:

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com


Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>



# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 


RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.northfalcons.com? [R=301,L]


### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

I hope it's 100% working for you.

Thanks for asking...